# 502 Bad gateway error for rails production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins

When I deploy my rails app in jenkins I am getting 502 gateway error for sending form data. But when I run the same in local with all three environments it is working properly.

Updated Question:
My rails app is working properly in local machine in all test,dev,prod environment.

But when I deploy it into Jenkins CI I am getting the above error for form data submission to another server.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @ElGavilan I updated the question.

Comment: So, have you tried to look at log files?(on remote server)

Comment: I am new for deployments .where i can find the log file whether in jenkins or in github.

Comment: on the remote server look at `var/log/nginx` directory and find `access.log` or `errors.log`. Share it here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I configured my unicorn server

```
timeout 5
```

but the response from the service call taking time so increased time

```
timeout 15
```

now it is working